# Be $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ Prove/disprove "if f is derivable in a dense subset $D ⊂ (a,b)$ then $f$ is derivable in $(a,b)$"

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm having a lot of trouble proving/disproving this statement!

> Be $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$. If f is derivable in a dense subset $D ⊂ (a,b)$ then f is derivable in $(a,b)$"

Somebody could help?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 3):

No. Take for example $f(x)=|x|$ on $\mathbb R$.